# Apple Itunes App Rejection due to Background mode Location

Tags: ios, iphone

I have uploaded my app but it got rejected with these questions:

1. How does your app utilize background mode location? Does this require persistent location?
2. Where can we locate this feature in your app?

My application needs to send data to server every 1 minute and user can also turn the tracking off. so I used background mode Location service.

I really couldn't understand what is their goal by asking these questions.

Comment: You say your app needs to send data to the server. WHY does it need to send that data? Where in the app is that data used. The questions are very clear. Just answer them.

Comment: you need to pass the viewcontroller name and describe the exact flow how your application using this location service so that they can locate it and approve it . Try to provide this in description section of application in iTune

Comment: @fogmeister Thanks, so no need to change info.plist or something like that?

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari viewController name or flow of going to that controller would be good?

Comment: why do you want to track your users movement in background? that does not serve the user's interests at the first glance (maybe your explanation is not completed); so the rejection seems valid based on that.

Comment: better to provide name and flow the same

Comment: Which part of the email from Apple says you have to change info.plist or anything like that? It is an email from a human being with two very straight forward questions. Hit the reply button and answer the questions. I am struggling to see why this is so difficult to understand?

Comment: @Fogmeister Okay. I got it. Thanks

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari Thanks bro. they answered within a screenshot why they can not see what happens.

Comment: okey great so your issue seems to solve now , right?

Comment: it is still in rejected phase. but if we show them how we are using and which part of application is they will accept it :) @ShobhakarTiwari

Comment: why not thats the way i did and many time it gets approved , try this way

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari : Did your app get approved?

Comment: yes it gets approved

Answer (score 1):

Check the Apple Developer Guidelines https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#location.

> 5.1.5 Location Services
>
> Use Location services in your app only when it is directly relevant to the features and services provided by the app. Location-based APIs shouldn’t be used to provide emergency services or autonomous control over vehicles, aircraft, and other devices, except for small devices such as lightweight drones and toys, or remote control car alarm systems, etc. Ensure that you notify and obtain consent before collecting, transmitting, or using location data. If your app uses background location services, be sure to explain the purpose in your app; refer to the Human Interface Guidelines for best practices on doing so.

You are not allowed to use the location for sending something different to the server than location data. With the questions they try to find out if your App has features, which requires the location and if for these features the persistent location is required or not.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Apple want to restrict for developers usage of background location, sometime without any explanation. We were asked for the same explanation of background location usage and after we provided full explanation and video demonstration we got following message from Apple:

> To continue review it would be appropriate to remove both background location and background bluetooth modes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use background location for other porpoise, so if you are using locations just to keep your app active in the background Apple will reject it.

> 2.5.4 Multitasking apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion,
>   local notifications, etc. If your app uses location background mode,
>   include a reminder that doing so may dramatically decrease battery
>   life.

If you need to send data each minutes is kind of complicated.
Probably the best solution is to use silent push notification, to trigger the app to send data to the server, but most probably you will need to increase the interval.

Comment: I worked so much on this issue. but it did not worked !